# "No set method providing array access" -- why does this happen in Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, kotlin, getter-setter

Here's the code.

```
val stack = Array(inputString.length + 1) { "" }
var current = 0
for ((i, char) in inputString.withIndex()) {
    if (char == '(') {
        current += 1
        continue
    } else if (char == ')') {
        val enclosedString = stack[current]
        stack[current - 1] = stack[current - 1] + enclosedString.reversed()
        current -= 1
        continue
    } else {
        stack[current] +=  char //here's the compile time error 
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error saying "No set method providing array access". I don't understand this.

If I change it to:

```
stack[current] = stack[current] + char
```

things work fine.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The cause of the error is the incorrect assignment of a `Char` variable to an `Array<String>`, you need to convert the `Char` to `String` before, and that's what is happening in the statement

```
stack[current] = stack[current] + char
```

The `+` function returns a new `String` concatenating with the string representation of the right side (i.e. it automatically call `toString` in the right operand). In other words, it is converting the `Char` variable `char` to `String` before the concatenation.

You can also convert it yourself.

```
stack[current] += char.toString()
```